# Find a side using similarity of triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I was given this problem by a professor. I think this is a straightfoward problem: by AA, triangles ABD and CBA are similar. After identifying corresponding sides one can see that $x=4$

[image]

**Question:** I was told this is incorrect by the professor. I cannot see what is wrong with my reasoning. What is the correct answer to this problem? Thank you!

Comment: @LionHeart Notice that $8*2.5=20$, and $4*2.5=10$, so we must have $x=4$

Comment: your answer is correct, since $\frac{x}{10}=\frac{8}{20}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put $CD = y$. Using similarity of two triangles you mentioned: $\dfrac{AB}{CB} = \dfrac{BD}{BA}=\dfrac{DA}{AC} \implies \dfrac{10}{x+y}=\dfrac{x}{10}=\dfrac{8}{20}\implies 8\cdot 10 = 20x\implies 20x = 80 \implies x = 4.$ Your answer is correct. Additionally, you can find $y$ and also $\theta$ if you really want. Namely, $y+4 = \dfrac{200}{8} = 25 \implies y = 21 = CD$.

Answer (score 1):

A simple application of similarity solves this problem.

For corresponding angles, notice that:

$$\frac{AD}{AC}=\frac{BD}{BA}$$.

Substituting the appropriate values above, we get:

$$\frac{8}{20}=\frac{x}{10}$$

This gives us $x=4$, which is correct. I'm not sure why your professor thought this was wrong, perhaps you can try asking him why he thinks its wrong and what the right method would be according to him.